# Nifi - how to add days to the date

Tags: datetime, apache-nifi, update-attribute

Could somebody tell me how I can add x number of days to a date attribute that is in the format ("yyyy-MM-dd") in Nifi.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use **toDate** function to convert into **unixtime** then use plus function with milliseconds and finally use **format** function to get your desired format

**Adding 1 day:**

```
${date:toDate("yyyy-MM-dd"):toNumber():plus(86400000):format("yyyy-MM-dd")}
```

**Example:**

i'm having **date** attribute to the flowfile with value as **2018-01-10** and want's to add 1 day to the **date** attribute value.

**Milliseconds** for 1 day(24hr) is **86400000** so in the below expression i'm adding one day to the date attribute value.

Add new attribute in update attribute processor as

**add_day**
and value as

> ```
> ${date:toDate("yyyy-MM-dd"):toNumber():plus(86400000):format("yyyy-MM-dd")}
> ```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Shu. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Shu What if I have a more elaborate date (with time) is there a way to do that using expression language (to add n number of days to an existing date and keep the time intact)